# Getting error "Nonetype has no attribute -- etc." and can't find anything to fix it. [-discord.py-]

Tags: python, async-await, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord command called "alert" that will make the bot say a specified message in the specified channel. This is my code:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(view_audit_log=True)
async def alert(ctx, channel, message):
    print(channel)
    channel = ctx.guild.get_channel(channel)
    await channel.send(message)
```

The error is here:

```
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Help?

Comment: First ask yourself why `get_channel` is returning `None`, then decide if that's an error or something you need to check for before trying to use the value of `channel`.

Comment: _Help?_ That's not much of a question, please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

This can't work because the argument to `get_channel` needs to be an `int` representing the channel id.  A better solution would be to use a converter:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(view_audit_log=True)
async def alert(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, message):
    await channel.send(message)
```